# Seeking tool like Merge of ArcGIS Desktop in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, merge

I'm looking for a tool that might do the same thing as "Merge" in ArcGis. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm
This tool allows you to select several entities, merge them and put them on another table in one manipulation without using another table. Except I need to use it in Qgis.

Do you know any plugin that would do the job?

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways to merge two or more layers. Just search in Processing Toolbox.

"*Merge vector layer*" from *QGIS geoalgorithms / Vector general tools* is similar than ArcGIS's merge tool:

[image]